# method pool in java

Tags: java, jvm

What is method pool?
my assumption is method pool is used for multi threading concept.
when more one thread while come and execute one method in a object,
the jvm will automatically create more than one method through a pool concept,
its dynamically grow by jvm,

my assumption is write or wrong?

please answer about that concept or will explain how this work?

sudo code example:

```
class A{
    method(obj o){
    //500 line code
    //bla bla
    //bla bla
    //bla bla
    //bla bla

    }
}
Run(){
A aa=new A();
aa.method();
}
thread1().start();
thread2().start();
.
.
.
.
thread99().start();
```

there is 99 object will be create or 99 method create in a pool?
this is my question please help me.

Comment: I don't believe there is any such thing as a method pool. Generally, you can pool instances of objects.

Comment: I agree with Elliott. I've never heard of such a thing as a method pool, and Google doesn't seem to have either. Where did you get this idea?

Comment: Do you mean *thread* pool?

Comment: no no thread pool is another concept

Comment: method of a class stays in the "code space" and execution of the method in each thread just running the program code on different stack memory. JVM do NOT need to make duplicate copies of the program code. The class loader only load it once and execute the instructions in every thread running that method (with runtime stack for each thread separately).

Comment: Counter example: Professor put the exam question (program code) on the projector screen and every student (thread) work on their own answer sheet (runtime stack). Different student may have different progress in answering the exam questions, like different thread's program counter may locate in different position of the program code.

Comment: how to access all thread in same one method how it will execute line by line using program counter, because each thread have stack,program counter in jvm.

Comment: thanks your effort ken cheung ex1: 1000 line in a method, 99 thread will execute in same method,how it allocate 1000 line in runtime stack for each thread,because each thread have one runtime satck. this concept is true.